# Kill Java Thread for testing purposes

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, jvm, kill

I'm currently testing a transaction system with ACID semantics implemented in Java. The system has callback handlers that allow to perform arbitrary debug actions during a transaction, e.g. to throw an exception that simulates an error.

However, in practice what can happen is the death of a thread (e.g. by OutOfMemoryError) or the death of the entire JVM (sigsev or OS process kill). I can see that it's impossible to simulate the unexpected shutdown of the JVM process in a JUnit test (because JUnit runs in the same JVM). But what about killing a thread? I know about `Thread#stop()`, but it's deprecated and moreover throws a `ThreadDeathError` in the thread. What I would like to simulate is the instantaneous "death" of a thread that prevents even `catch(Throwable t)` clauses from firing. Can this be done in Java, without killing the JUnit test runner alongside it?

Again, this is **not for production use**, it's strictly testing only.

Comment: How about explicitly throw an `OutOfMemoryError` in the thread?

Comment: Nice idea, but I'm not sure if a "manually" thrown `OutOfMemoryError` really has the same effect on the JVM as a "real" OoME. One could argue that it's an idea to allocate memory until the OoME is reached, but that way the JUnit test environment may be damaged as well...

Comment: Or just try to load very big file. OOM is very easy to reproduce.

Comment: @Nambari: Yes, that's certainly true. However, what the JVM actually DOES when a OOM occurs seems to be rather non-deterministic. You see, I don't want to "damage" the JUnit test thread, the test should still behave deterministically and therefore reliably.

Comment: AFAIK, OOM kills entire JVM process (not just thread). You need to run your Unit tests from other process to test this well.

Comment: "I'm not sure if..." how about trying it :) I'm not saying it will do everything you need, but it might be an easy thing to try, if only to eliminate.

Comment: @Nambari No, it actually kills just a thread. I had to fight with systems where that happened and it *seems* to continue working but some important threads are just gone.

Comment: @RealSkeptic: Can you add more info about "it seems to continue working"? and your statement is little bit conflicting, you are saying "just a thread" but at end added "some important threads are gone". My understanding is "thread which threw OOM + These important threads" = JVM process.

Comment: @Nambari: I had a system that has several hundred threads that are started at startup and are supposed to stay alive (waiting for some event and performing a task when it happens, etc.). Then there was a mysterious OOM in one or two of them. Those threads would die, but the other threads continue living, so the JVM stays alive. You can connect to its monitoring system, you can submit requests to it - but somewhere there is a queue that gets full and nothing reads from it. All you see are OOMs in the error stream.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Ok, got it. My guess is those tasks are daemon threads, which are accepting requests (but failing to execute the business), jvm staying live is interesting thing I have never heard of. Any idea which jvm implementation you were using?

Comment: @Nambari - Sun JRE 1.4 (I didn't say it was recent...). It's easy to set up a test to see if thread A stays alive when thread B tries to allocate unavailable memory.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, Yeah 1.4 is very old. Whenever I saw OOM my monitoring (jconsole) app lost connection to JVM, but didn't closely monitor about the status of threads.

Comment: How about putting that thread into an infinite loop?

Comment: In a prior job, I had to create tests that caused system failures using junit.  I then create a ProcessTest that would spawn a new jvm.  The ProcessTest would provide a socket port that the spawned process would use to communicate with it.  Those callbacks will included setup,test,teardown callbacks that were forwarded to the junit test result class.  You could create something similar that you can use to test the above conditions that would also include killing the process.  The ProcessTest class could also include callbacks that you can use to synchronize a particular condition.

Comment: Continuing my comment, the solution was using junit 3.x but I'm not sure how this can be done with junit 4.  Using this type of test, you could make the jvm crash using a kill or generate a OOM error.  These actions would be performed within a separate process that would not affect the other junit tests being run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the instantaneous "death" of a thread that prevents even catch(Throwable t) clauses from firing. Can this be done in Java?

**No. It's impossible.**

JVM uses OS threads and thus relies on the underlying OS scheduler. So in JVM level, JVM can't preempt a java thread. A java thread must volunteer to be suspended. (It's common case, but still platform- and JVM-specific）

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
  Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      while (true) {
        int i = 0;
        i++;
      }
    }
  });
  t1.start();
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  t1.stop();
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  System.out.println(t1.isAlive());
}
```

In the above code, `stop()` worked. But you might wonder why an infinite loop without `wait()/sleep()` looks like "doesn't volunteer to be suspended"?

`stop()` raise an `asynchronous exception` in `t1`. `t1` thread can detect the async exception by polling.

From [Java Virtual Machine Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.10):

> The stop methods may be invoked by one thread to affect another thread or all the threads in a specified thread group. They are asynchronous because they may occur at any point in the execution of the other thread or threads. An internal error is considered asynchronous
>
> A simple implementation might poll for asynchronous exceptions at the point of each control transfer instruction.

Which means, in the compiled code, at the end of the while-loop before `jump`, there's an instruction to poll the exception. If the exception exists, the `t1` thread jump to exception handler and stop by it self.

So if I make the thread ignore all exceptions, and if the thread doesn't stop by it self, it's impossible to kill a java thread.

Here's an example where `stop()` doesn't work:

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws InterruptedException {
  Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      while (true) {
        try {
          while (true) {
            int i = 0;
            i++;
          }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
  });
  t1.start();
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  t1.stop();
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  System.out.println(t1.isAlive());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was afraid that the answer would be "no, it's impossible" to begin with, but I learned a few new things about the JVM.